# License violation detected. Unlicensed module(s) detected. Module is a 10 day trial

Tags: module, appcelerator

I installed a module from the Appcelerator Marketplace. This module was a trial version, but I should still be able to use the module on the Appcelerator Platform, but I am recieving an error that states "License violation detected. Unlicensed module(s) detected." Do I just have to simply purchase the module, or is there a way to test the module with the 10 day trial? Thank you.

Comment: You'd be better off searching Google for information about that specific module, or asking the creators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of installing the module in the Titanium folder, install the module locally to your mobile project.

```
 Mobile Project Folder/modules/iphone/com.modulename.blah
```

Then inside the module folder you will find a 'manifest' file. Open this in a text editor and change the 'guid' string to be the SAME guid as you find in Tiapp.xml (near the top).

In Titanium studio, go to Project > Clean and clean your project (emptying the /Build folder) and re-build. If it's going to work and this is a free trial with no issues then it should now work.

Another trick I haven't had to use for a long long time is to actually change the guid of my app in tiapp.xml and then also do the same for my modules. Clean & Rebuild you should be good to go. Failing that you will need to speak to the module developer for assistance.